# Regex performance issues with possible back tracking?

Tags: java, regex

I have the following input/output and regex code that works fine (for the below input/output).

-- input --

```
keep this

      keep this too

     Bye
------ Remove Below ------
  remove all of this
```

-- output --

```
keep this

      keep this too

     Bye
```

-- code --

```
    String text = "keep this\n       \n"
            + "      keep this too\n      \n     Bye\n------ Remove Below ------\n  remove all of this\n";
    System.out.println(text);
    Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^(.*?)(-+)(.*?)Remove Below(.*?)(-+)(.*?)$",
             Pattern.DOTALL);
    Matcher m = PATTERN.matcher(text);
    if (m.find()) {
        // remove everything as expected (from about input->regex->output)
        text =  ((m.group(1)).replaceAll("[\n]+$", "")).replaceAll("\\s+$", "");
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
        System.out.println(text);
    }
```

Ok, so this works great.  However, this is for a test with the defined input output. When I get large files that I have to parse that contain the following sequence of characters/patterns I'm seeing the code take a while to execute (4-5sec) per the Find() method on files that are say 100k in size that have the following pattern.  In fact sometimes I'm not sure if it's returning or not...when I step though as a debug test the find() method hangs and my client disconnects.

NOTE: There is nothing to match in this file...but this is a pattern that is taxing my regex.

-- 100k file --

```
junk here
more junk here
o o o (even more junk per the ellipses) 
-------------------------------------this is junk
junk here
more junk here
o o o (even more junk per the ellipses) 
-------------------------------------this is junk
junk here
more junk here
o o o (even more junk per the ellipses) 
-------------------------------------this is junk
junk here
more junk here
o o o (even more junk per the ellipses) 


this repeats from above to make up the 100k file.
```

-- ASK --

> How can I optimize the above regex to handle large file patterns from
>   above as such or is this normal for regex parse speed (4-6sec) let along hanging altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're only interested in text above `------ Remove Below ------` line, you don't need to match everything. Just match what you want by shortening your regex and avoid excessive matching and backtracking.

```
Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^(.*?)-+ *Remove Below *-+", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. This is really what I'm looking for and it worked like a charm and with great performance. One question is why you don't have to include the trailing $?

Comment: We actually don't need to match any $ here since we are grabbing our text which comes before Remove line.

Comment: Thanks again.  Once last ask: what is the difference between (.*?) per your solution ... let's say it was (.*). What is really the difference (non-greedy vs. greedy)?  Can you elaborate some?

Comment: With greedy match `.*` will try to grab as much as possible thus `-+` after that will only match single hyphen. But with non-greedy quantifier `.*?` will match just the text before `------` which will be fully matched by `-+`

Answer (score 1):

You are absolutely right, this is a traceback nightmare!

Avoid possible matches when using wildcards. Some tactics, that might help:

if the number of '-' is known use a concrete string to test:

```
^(.*?)(------ Remove Below ------)(.*)$
```

or at least a little more concrete

```
^(.*?)-*-\s*Remove Below\s*--*(.*?)$
```

be more precise:

```
^(.*?)(-+)([^-]*)Remove Below([^-]*)(-+)(.*?)$
```

be greedy if you can:

```
^(.*)(-+)(.*?)Remove Below(.*?)(-+)(.*?)$
```

do not include in matches if not needed:

```
^(.*?)-+.*?Remove Below.*?-+.*?$
```

of course, depending on your input quality you can combine these concepts:

```
^(.*)------ Remove Below ------.*$
```

In your case, parse line by line and when it matches `^.*-+\s*Remove Below\s*-+.*$` stop amending

Comment: These are great even fantastic best practices and recommendations.  I will give them a try for sure.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure the stuff to remove is in the end of the file reverse your input string. That should help you quite a lot. Instead of

```
Matcher m = PATTERN.matcher(text);
```

use

```
Matcher m = PATTERN.matcher(new StringBuilder(text).reverse());
```

Remember to also reverse a pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a third party regex library. [Here you have benchmarks](http://tusker.org/regex/regex_benchmark.html).